# dhtmltooltip with text in an array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use dhtmltooltip with texts for tips in an array.

HTML :

```
<div id="div0">This div is tooltipped using the script<br />
wished tooltip = Paris.<br />
</div>
<br />
<div id="div1">
This div is tooltipped using the script<br />
wished tooltip = London.
</div>

<div id="dhtmltooltip"></div>
```

Script :

```
I = new Array();
I[0] = "Paris";
I[1] = "London";

for (var num=0; num<I.length; num++) 
{
mytext = I[num];
div = document.getElementById('div'+num);
div.setAttribute("onmouseover", "ddrivetip(mytext)");//FF and IE>8
div.setAttribute("onmouseout", "hideddrivetip()");//FF and IE>8
}
```

I use the dhtmltooltip script found [here](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex5/dhtmltooltip.htm).

The problem is that the second tip (London) is used for both tips.

It must be a trivial error but I can't find it.

You can see a test file [here](http://lpae002.free.fr//hack_hotpot/tests/test_dhtmlTT.html).

Could someone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: At the end of the loop, `mytext`'s value is set to `London`. On mouseover for both, it's pretty much doing `ddrivetip("London")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, all of these variables are globals and that in itself is probably causing you an issue.

But your actual problem is here:

```
div.setAttribute("onmouseover", "ddrivetip(mytext)");
```

Change it to this

```
div.setAttribute("onmouseover", "ddrivetip('" + mytext + "')");
```

Comment: Woops I meant to put that into quotes.  Check answer again, fixed

Answer (score 0):

The problem is two-fold. Firstly, `mytext` is a global var when you probably want it to be local. This isn't causing trouble now but mark my words, with this sort of thing it'll bite you. The other problem is that you're not attaching events properly. Change this:

```
div.setAttribute("onmouseover", "ddrivetip(mytext)");
```

to this:

```
div.onmouseover = 'ddrivetip("' + mytext + '")';
```

Or better yet, use closures and `addEventListener`.

Comment: The script is a little part of a big one where the array must be global. Unfortunately your solution comes to the disparition of the tooltips. I'm not at ease with eventhandlers. How could I use "closures and addEventListener" ?(I avoid saying thanks because stackoverflow told me to avoid it but I think it very much)

Comment: Sorry about the variables. You are right : the array must be global but mytext has to be local.